# Redirect non-www to www while preserving protocol

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, no-www

I am aware of the fact that there are tons of questions in this section and in server fault dealing with re-directions from `non-www` to `www` URLs. But I couldn't find one dealing with this issue while preserving protocol.

I am no mod-rewrite expert, and my code is just copy/pasted... Here's what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld$1 [R=301,L]
```

So now `http://domain.tld` and `https://domain.tld` are forwarded to `http://www.domain.tld`. How do I make it so that HTTPS stays on HTTPS while HTTP stays on HTTP?

Comment: Just for anyone who finds this question... the above mod_rewrite directives look as if they are intended for the server config, as opposed to .htaccess. If this was used in .htaccess then an additional slash is required in the substitution: `http://www.domain.tld/$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little information. Best practices indicate that trafic from HTTP has to be redirected to HTTPS. If your site is reachable on HTTPS, no more need to HTTP.

I think you can associate `no-www` redirection to `www` with HTTP redirection to HTTPS.

Moreover, be careful of duplicate content if your site is reachable with HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code you have, just use it again with `HTTPS_HOST` too (more chars escaped with `\` even though it may not be needed in most servers). As w3d [noted in a comment above](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/redirect-non-www-to-www-while-preserving-protocol/72566#comment82856_38139), this is designed to work in a htaccess file because of the `/` before the `$1`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.tld\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.tld\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Here is the one we use sometimes to cover addon domains situations. Consider most addon domains use a utility subdomain on a host domain, which is often accessible. This would also forward the sub and www-sub:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.hostdomain\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.hostdomain\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.tld\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain\.hostdomain\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.domain\.hostdomain\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.tld\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

There are methods to make these combined as 1 rule-set, but it's nicer IMO to keep them as separated `HTTP` and `HTTPS` "routers". You can play with the targets in each if you wanna enforce either-or SSL mode too.